# Encoding set of structs in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, archiving

I have old code:

```
let output=NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: path) as? Set<Cloud>
```

where Cloud is a struct.
And I get warning:

```
'unarchiveObject(withFile:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead
```

Yet when I try to use that code I get an error saying:

```
 Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that 'Set<Cloud>' conform to 'NSCoding'
```

and

```
 Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that 'Set<Cloud>' inherit from 'NSObject'
```

Yet if I try to add those protocols to the struct it answers:

```
  Non-class type 'Cloud' cannot conform to class protocol 'NSCoding'
```

what is quite logical as it is a struct.
Which code should I use to encode a set of structs?

Comment: What's properties are inside `Cloud`? Could it conforms to `Codable` instead?

Comment: Objects conforming to `NSCoding` must be sub**class**es of `NSObject`. Consider to use `Codable`.

Comment: In cases where you need to work with `NSCoding`, you need to use `NSSet` explicitly. Furthermore, `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is an Objective C API that *only* works with `NSObject`s. If you need to use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` (and there are still some legitimate reasons, e.g. `Codable` doesn't support object aliasing or cycles), then you need to add some DTO classes that conform to `NSCoding`.